Porting "Visual Studio for Mac" Project to Visual Studio Code...Is it possible?
Can Visual Studio Code port over/convert a project that was originally developed in Visual Studio for Mac? I have to publish an emergency update and just found out Visual Studio for Mac has been discontinued which was the environment it was originally written in.

Visual studio code isn't a compiler, so it doesn't matter here.  Start by building via cli and work through any errors that come up.

Visual Studio for Mac is an obsolete version of Visual Studio. VSCode is not Visual Studio (they're totally separate applications that, unfortunately, have confusingly similar names). There is no direct import path from Visual Studio to VSCode, whether you're on Windows or Mac. You're going to have to bite the bullet and spend some time moving things over and correcting issues that arise as you go.

Thank you. I originally started out with Xamarin, ported it over to Visual Studio for Mac and now this. Sometime I think I would had been just better off writing it separately for Andorid and iOS.
